# Reading meta content using JSTL

Tags: jstl

I have meta something like this

```
<meta content="Review, Living Social, Travelzoo, Zozi, Rush 49, Groupon" name="keywords" />
```

I need to read the content of the meta tag using JSTL.

I did it using javascript, but need it to be done with JSTL

Please let me know if any suggestions

Comment: The question doesn't make much sense. JSTL is a set of JSP tags, allowing generating HTML pages on the server. What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: I actually have to read the content in the meta and then take the comma separated string.

Comment: And what does the JSTL has to do with this? Use Java code tp parse this string and extract the content.

Comment: JB Nizet, I am very new jstl I am not sure if we can use it. not sure if we can use jstl to read value from a html tag. pls let me know if we can use jstl for this purpose.

Comment: You've still not explained what you want to do precisely. Where is this tag? Where do you get it from? What do you want to achieve? JSTL is used by JSPs, which are view components, which are used to generate HTML. To parse things, use Java code.

Comment: Understood JB Nizet. I was wrong somewhere.  I am much clear on JSTL now. Thanks for your patience.